# knitr - Rmarkdown Execution halted problem

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have encountered the following error when I try to knit my r-markdown document:

> processing file: Exam.Rmd
> Error in parse_block(g[-1], g[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPXqg.png), params.src, markdown_mode) :
> Duplicate chunk label 'setup', which has been used for the chunk:

> knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
> Calls:  ... process_file -> split_file -> lapply -> FUN -> parse_block
> Execution halted

[image: Messege]

What is my next course of action?

Comment: you have two chunks labeled "setup" change one of them

Comment: @rawr i have ```{r setup, include=FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

Comment: That's one of the two; there's another one that's labeled `setup`. There can be only one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The error says "duplicate chunk label". All chunks must have unique names so try putting another label to the duplicate chunk :)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this line got copy pasted some how in your code

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning = FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message = FALSE)
```

Delete the duplicate and you are good to go.